# Magento 2 Product Image not full width on page load

Tags: magento2

How to fix this issue on viewing a product in magento 2?
The image is set on that height and width on page load but when you select any color in the choices, the product size restores
[image]

this is the how it looks when you selected a color...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, it seems it was a bootstrap issue, Bootstrap was forcing the product media container to be a display:flex; and the javascript needs it to be a display:block; 
I added this to my CSS and this fixed it.


`.page-layout-1column .product.media {
   display: block !important;
}`

Comment: not working on my case. facing same issue.